# Google Apps Script User Interface

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

Well, I've been reading the documentation and I believe that I'm calling functions and passing parameters correctly, but for the life of me I can't get this simple UI code to work.

I'm generating a UI for a Spreadsheet using the following code:

```
function checkOut() {

  var app = buildUI();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}

function buildUI() {
  var gui = UiApp.createApplication();
  gui.setTitle("Check-Out/Check-In");
  gui.setStyleAttribute("background", "lavender");

  // Absolute panel for setting specific locations for elements
  var panel = gui.createAbsolutePanel();

  // Equipment ID#s Label
  var equipmentIDLabel = gui.createLabel("Equipment ID#s");
  equipmentIDLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  equipmentIDLabel.setSize("20px", "125px");
  equipmentIDLabel.setStyleAttributes({background: "SteelBlue", color: "white"});

  // Add all components to panel
  panel.add(equipmentIDLabel, 10, 0);

  gui.add(panel);

  return gui;
}

function getUIdata(eventInfo) {
  // I know how to get the data from each element based on ID
}
```

It generates the Absolute Panel correctly when `checkOut()` is called, but the EquipmentIDLabel is never added to the panel. I am basing the code on the simplistic design I created in the GUI builder (that will be deprecated in a few days, which is why I am writing the code so that I can change it later):

[image: Nothing special]

So what exactly is going wrong here? If I can figure out how to add one element, I can infer the rest by looking at the docs. I've never been any good at GUI development!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use grid as an interesting alternative... here is an example :

```
// define styles
var labelStyle = {background: "SteelBlue", color: "white",'textAlign':'center','line-height':'20px','vertical-align':'middle','font-family':"Arial, sans-serif",'fontSize':'10pt'};// define a common label style
var fieldStyle = {background: "white", color: "SteelBlue",'font-family':"Courrier, serif",'fontSize':'11pt'};// define a common label style

function checkOut() {
  var app = buildUI();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
}

function buildUI() {
  var gui = UiApp.createApplication();
  gui.setTitle("Check-Out/Check-In");
  gui.setStyleAttribute("background", "lavender");
  var panel = gui.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','10px');
  var grid = gui.createGrid(4,2).setWidth('300').setCellPadding(10);//define grid size in number of row & cols
  var equipmentID = ['equipmentIDLabel','equipmentIDLabel1','equipmentIDLabel2','equipmentIDLabel3'];// define labels in an array of strings
  for(var n=0 ;n<equipmentID.length ; n++){;// iterate
    var equipmentIDLabel = gui.createLabel(equipmentID[n]).setWidth('125').setStyleAttributes(labelStyle);
    var equipmentIDField = gui.createTextBox().setText('Enter value here').setName(equipmentID[n]).setSize("125", "20").setStyleAttributes(fieldStyle);
    grid.setWidget(n,0,equipmentIDLabel).setWidget(n,1,equipmentIDField);
  }
  gui.add(panel.add(grid));
  return gui;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, adding a grid seemed to work fine. I don't know exactly what the problem was with the Absolute Panel... it's interesting because the grid is added fine, and then I just add a button after the grid (not *in* the grid), and it appears just fine. In any case, I have it working perfectly now, and I'm too lazy to figure out why a single element couldn't be added to the Absolute Panel such as the label I created in my original post. Thanks again Serge :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the absolute panel offset method is a little capricious and take control of your positioning, in my tests I have been able to position panels that are visible in the following way:

```
  panel.add(equipmentIDLabel);
  panel.add(equipmentIDField,150,0);
  panel.add(otherLabel);
  panel.add(otherField, 150, 20);
```

Try it out with trial and error, you may get the UI you need, if not I would move to an alternate layout, verticalPanel is a little better behaved and of course you can use forms as well.

Another small bug is that you inverted the length and hight in equipmentIDLabel.setSize("20px", "125px");

Let me know if I can be of more assitance

Comment: It's interesting that my label couldn't be added to the Absolute Panel, but a grid could be added. In fact, adding the grid first allowed for elements to actually be added to the Absolute Panel afterward using the same parameters as in my original post. I have no idea why that would happen, and I never really did any GUI development before now so even the basics are making me struggle. In any case, thanks for trying! PS - I did reverse the parameter order for the `setSize` function, and nothing changed so I don't think that was the issue :P

Comment: Looking at my code I can see that the first line should be without any parameter ... i've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem in your code is the following line :

```
// Add all components to panel
  panel.add(equipmentIDLabel, 10, 0);
```

Simply change it to : `panel.add(equipmentIDLabel);`

..and you will see the field (at position 0,0).

As patt0 observes, you can then add OTHER components and use positioning.  It seems to be a limitation of adding the first field to an absolutePanel.

Of course, the Google Script gui is now deprecated (since December 2014) but I was interested to try your code and see that it still basically executes (as at Feb 2016).